# Why is the flag `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` reset when building the Linux kernel?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, compiling

I have built the Linux kernel, but I wanted to do it without building the debug package.

I know that it's possible to disable the flag `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`, via `scripts/config` (with either `--set str ""` or `--disable`).

However, I'm confused, because when I invoke `make deb-pkg`, the flag is reset to the value `y`, so that the package is built.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour changed slightly in 5.18, which may be why you’re seeing this. [`DEBUG_INFO` is now a selection](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f9b3cd24578401e7a392974b3353277286e49cee), so `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` is set based on other configuration settings. To disable `DEBUG_INFO`, you need to enable `DEBUG_INFO_NONE` and make sure all the other selections are disabled (`DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT`, `DEBUG_INFO_DWARF4`, `DEBUG_INFO_DWARF5`).